# how do I avoid the overlapping error bars and replace X and Y axis?

Tags: python, plot, overlapping, yaxis, x-axis

I am new to matplotlib and I am asking for your help to solve my little problem. I am sharing the graph below, here are the questions:

1- I want x-axis and y-axis replace
2- And most important for me is that errorbars should be horizontal (in graph below these are vertical).

Some errorbars in the graph is overlapping and I tried to avoid this problem using transform command. As I said before if I can manage the replacement of X and Y axis I would be happy.

Below I am sharing the code I wrote:

```
import ax as ax
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.transforms import Affine2D

y_values = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
p1 = [1, 0.77, 0.67, 0.85, 0.78, 1.05, 0.63]
p2 = [3, 2, 1.5, 1.20, 1.10, 1.40, 1.10]

x_err = [0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5, 0.3, 0.2, 0.3]
y_err = [0.6, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5, 0.3, 0.2, 0.3]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
trans1 = Affine2D().translate(-0.1, 0.0) + ax.transData
trans2 = Affine2D().translate(+0.1, 0.0) + ax.transData

er1 = ax.errorbar(y_values, p1, x_err, marker="o", linestyle="none", transform=trans1)
er2 = ax.errorbar(y_values, p2, y_err, marker="o", linestyle="none", transform=trans2)
```

[errorbar plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFLZv.png)